# Django ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings.local

Tags: python, django, settings, importerror

I'm setting up a site in django with multiple settings files as recommended in 2 scoops of django where settings.py is replaced with a settings directory that contains multiple settings files (local.py, etc.). My development server will run fine when I leave settings.py in the default location, but when I move it into the new settings directory I created and run the development server with:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.local
```

I get the error:

> ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings.local' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings.local

I have added the directory to the python path and it shows up when I go into python and enter:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

I am running out of ideas. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `touch __init__.py` in your `settings` directory

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. All I had to do was copy __init__.py into the directory. Looking back at 2 scoops of django they copied an __init__.py file into the settings directory I just missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python needs to have an **__init__.py** file in your root directory so it can consider the subfolders as importable.
Please try adding  **__init__.py** to your root directory and run 
`python manage.py runserver` in the terminal 
```